# Precedence of operators in Siddhi logical patterns

Tags: siddhi

From the documentation:

> #### Logical sequence
>
> Pattern not only matches event arriving on the temporal order but it
>   can also correlate events having logical relationships.
>
> Keywords like "and" and "or" can be used interred of "->" to
>   illustrate the logical relationship.

I have two questions:

1. When I mix "and", "or" and "->" in an event, how is this evaluated? Is it  simply left or right associative, or do the 3 operators have different precedences? Say I have "A and B -> C or D", is this evaluated as "((A and B) -> C) or D", "A and (B->(C or D))", or something else altogether?
2. As a follow up question, can I explicitly use parentheses in the triggers to force how the trigger should be interpreted? The documentation does not mention it, but siddhi does allow me to create some triggers with parentheses, e.g. "A -> (B or C) -> D" is accepted (although "(A->B) or (C->D)" is not). Does this have the intended effect, and what are the exact rules for when you can and cannot add parentheses?

Answer (score 0):

`"A and B -> C or D"` will match for A and B arriving in any order `(A->B) or (B->A)` and then C or D arriving.

You can't use nesting in any order, nesting makes sense when we add every keyword, i.e for every which sequence/event you want the pattern matching to repeat.

E.g `every(A->B)->C` here for every A followed by B there should be a C. 
If there are events like A1, C1, A2, B2, B3, C2, C3  then the above only matches for A1, B2, C2.